# I am trying to put the content an String to ListView

Tags: java

I am trying to put the content an String to ListView. After running the code, the object of ListView contains null. I am not sure where is the problem? any help please!! Not to forget that employee it an object of Tap class which is located in TabLayout.

```
//Step 1. Create and initialize the array.
String[] temp = {"Book", "Notebook", "pen", "pencil"};

//Step 2. Convert the array to ObservablList
ObservableList<String> strList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(temp);

//Step 3. Convert the ObservableList to ListView
ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(strList);

//Step 4. Add the content of ListView to the employee Tap. 
employee.setContent(listView);
```

The except is thrown when step 4 is executed. I think this happens because of step 3. The object of the elements ListView are null.

Comment: You got the idea wrong dear.

`listView.getItems().add(list)` where list is a `List` or `ObservableList`.

Plus you cannot convert `observablelist` to `listview,` `listview` is a `View`, something you can see on the UI.

If you can show us the stacktrace we can help you more

Comment: The code is exactly how the book explains the issue (to show the element of string array in a ListView). Is there any other way to import the elements of an array in listview?

Answer (score 1):

For reference, a tab's [`setContent()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#setContent(javafx.scene.Node)) method accepts *any* [`Node`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html), including a [`ListView`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html).

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/51795358/230513
 */
public class TabList extends Application {

    private Tab createTab(String title) {
        String[] temp = {"Book", "Notebook", "Pen", "Pencil"};
        ObservableList<String> strList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(temp);
        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(strList);
        Tab tab = new Tab(title);
        tab.setContent(listView);
        return tab;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        tabPane.getTabs().add(createTab("Manager"));
        tabPane.getTabs().add(createTab("Employee"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(tabPane));
        stage.setTitle("ListView in Tab");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```